# Why do inherited data annotations stop working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

If someone misses the tags: I'm using .NET MVC5 to develop a web application, and using data annotations for validation (both client and server side).

I wanted to customise the built in annotations (Required, StringLentgth, Range etc.) to suit my needs a little better. I started by making my own class that inherits `RequiredAttribute`, added literally nothing, and replaced `Required` on my viewmodel with `Test`. I ran that, expecting it to work 100% like it did before, but to my surprise, the validation stopped working completely for the said field. In HTML, the `data-val-required="......"` that was there previously, simply didn't show up any more.

My new attribute (I've tried it with or without usage specification, result is the same):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class TestAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    // Literally nothing new, same as superclass.
}
```

The annotated property in viewmodel:

```
// Before, works.
[Required]
public int WorkerId { get; set; }

// After, doesn't work.
[Test]
public int WorkerId { get; set; }
```

So, how does this work? How come the behavior changes simply by subclassing? How should I inherit attributes to inherit their behaviour? Isn't this a violation of Liskov substitution principle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'd expect server side validation to continue to work but the reason client-side validation stops working is that you have to tell ASP.NET which adapter to use to generate the client-side validation JavaScript. If you're not actually changing the behaviour of RequiredAttribute you could just use its adapter. Put the below code in your Application_Start() method.

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(Test), typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

Comment: This seems to be the best way. I presume you can do the same for the rest of inbuilt attributes?

Comment: Yeah, and if you need to override the client side validation because you're changing the validation logic there's a way of doing that too.

Comment: Yeah, I have a bunch of custom attributes with client side already, I just wanted to write my own "required" with localised messages. I just added the setup of resource file to the constructor of my new attribute that inherits from `RequiredAttribute` and it works like a charm. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

[Update :  AS Davor pointed out in comment.  It is a WRONG!! answer.   Just leaving this for anyone come across the same.  Sorry. ]

The Required attribute referenced in MSDN as a non-inheritable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

```html
  [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, 
 Inherited = false)]

  public sealed class RequiredAttribute : Attribute
```

Comment: You've got the wrong namespace/class, it's this one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.100).aspx

When I open the RequiredAttribute in VS this is in the definition: `[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1813:AvoidUnsealedAttributes", Justification = "We want users to be able to extend this class")]`. So they explicitly want us to be able to inherit it.